# Optional type hint in Google Style Guide

Tags: python, type-hinting, google-style-guide

I have a doubt regarding `Optional` type hint in the [Google Python Style Guide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html). In section 3.19.5, the following is shown as correct usage:

```
def func(a: Optional[Text], b: Optional[Text] = None) -> Text:
```

I don't understand `a: Optional[Text]`. Why is it not `a: Optional[Text] = None`?

Comment: Presumably just because the first argument doesn't have a default value. Why *would* it have `= None`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What value will `a` take in the function when nothing is passed?

Comment: @Carcigenicate then why the type hint `Optional`? I seem to be missing something in my understanding.

Comment: It won't take any value; it's a `TypeError`, the function never gets entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because it's `Optional` doesn't mean that it needs a default argument, or that the argument is "optional".

`Optional[Text]` means "it can be a `Text` object, or it can be `None`". The `None` value need not be a specified default though; it can be user supplied. You may, for whatever reason, want the user to pass that argument, even if it's just `None`.

Part of the confusion might be the use of the term "optional" here. "Optional" in this context doesn't mean that the argument is optional. It means that it's an [*option type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type).